# How to assign RGB value to the Entry in Tkinter? (without classes)

Tags: python, tkinter, spyder, rgb, tkinter-entry

sorry if I am being stupid, but. I am trying to create a custom cyan border with RGB values of (122,197,205) to a border of an Entry.

```
#Typing field
typingField = Entry(gui, bg='grey',highlightthickness=5, width=40, font=('Arial 27'))
typingField.config(highlightbackground = "red", highlightcolor= "red")
typingField.place(x=92, y=310)
```

right now I have set it to make a red one, but I need cyan one. I tryied to just write:

```
typingField.config(highlightbackground = (122,197,205), highlightcolor= (122,197,205))
```

but it doesn't work. I searched online but came to no results explaining how to do it without classes. I must not use them. Please enlighten me

Comment: What exactly do you mean by without classes?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a string of hex values. Like you would in html or css.

```
name_entry.config(highlightbackground="#7ac5cd", highlightcolor="#7ac5cd")
```

A simple function (minus error checking) for converting the rgb values to a hex string would be.

```
def rgb2hex(r, g, b):
    return f"#{r:02x}{g:02x}{b:02x}"
```